# How to create and pass unique template reference variable in Angular?

Tags: angular, kendo-angular-ui

I have a scenario where i need to add kendo-popup to every element in my array, the problem is kendo-popup takes "anchor(parent)" as input to display the popup. Below is sample code.

```
  <span #anchor{{index}} *ngFor="let route of breadcrumbs;index as index;" class="item" (click)="executeAction(route)">
    <span >{{route.label}}</span>
    <span (click)="openPopup($event)"> <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i> </span>
    <kendo-popup [anchor]="anchor{{index}}" [open]="popupOpen" (closePopup)="close()" position="fixed"></kendo-popup>
```

As you can see, i want to create and pass template reference variable to kendo-popup as ["anchor0", "anchor1"]. But above code is not working.
I have also tried few other techniques but none has helped yet.
Can anyone please help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you need a template reference here, you altready have the index, simply pass it.

Comment: Input to anchor is ElementRef object. Which i can get by using template reference variable.

Comment: have you tried passing breadcrumbs[index]  this to anchor input

Comment: Yes, but that is not an Element. Its just a value in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template reference variables are scoped to the template they are defined in. A structural directive creates a nested template and, therefore, introduces a separate scope.

So your template reference variables are already unique because they are inside ngFor embedded view.

```
<span #anchor *ngFor="let route of breadcrumbs;index as index;" class="item" (click)="executeAction(route)">
    <span >{{route.label}}</span>
    <span (click)="openPopup($event)"> <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i> </span>
    <kendo-popup [anchor]="anchor" [open]="popupOpen" (closePopup)="close()" position="fixed"></kendo-popup>
```

Comment: I tried even that, but didn't worked. It opens all the pop ups on click of any trigger.

Comment: this actually was working but i was not able to catch it, since i am using a common variable to open pop up i.e: popupOpen. It was triggering open and close for all the popups. Hence it tricked me to think, it wasnt working. After fixing this variable issue, it worked. Thanks. :)